# Restler GET works, but POST returns 404

Tags: php, restler

I have a simple class for Restler (http://luracast.com/products/restler) like so:

```
class Team extends PostgreSQL {
    function post($name) {
    }

    function players($teamId) {
    }
}
```

If I run a curl GET, like so: `curl http://.../team/players/1`

I get back the expected data.  If I run a POST, like below, I always get a 404:

`curl -X POST http://.../team -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name": "Team name here"}`

I'm not understanding why the POST gives a 404 Not Found.

Comment: I don't see the whole URLs here, but the one with post seems to end with just "/team", meaning it doesn't include the function name...

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically call the post method via Restler's routing?

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar enough with Restler. It's just that your GET points to /team/players/1 and your POST to /team . I assumed you wanted to make the same request... I would first try to make a POST to /team/post

Answer (score 0):

`curl -X POST http://.../team/Team%20Name%20Here`

That's how it expects the post to come through.